# ESP32-C3-WROOM: error flashing chip

Tags: microcontroller, uart, esp32, ttl, ft232

I am developing an ESP32-C3-WROOM custom board, but when I tried to flash the chip using UART (FT232D USB-TTL) and Arduino IDE, I got the message "A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32-C3: Timed out waiting for packet header". I have tried pulling up GPIO 8, but no results.

[image]

Comment: Do you receive any serial data from the esp when you power it up in bootloader mode? Use a terminal program to verify. Pcb layout is fairly critical as the esp can draw high peak currents. The location and spec of the 10uF cap is important. It needs to be a 25V or greater in order to get adequate capacitance due to the dc bias derating.

Comment: yes i got some messages from esp chip like                                                                      10:30:06.132 -> ESP-ROM:esp32s2-rc4-20191025
10:30:06.132 -> Build:Oct 25 2019
10:30:06.132 -> rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
10:30:06.172 -> SPIWP:0xee
10:30:06.172 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
10:30:06.172 -> load:0x3ffe6100,len:0x510
10:30:06.172 -> load:0x4004c000,len:0xa50
10:30:06.172 -> load:0x40050000,len:0x28bc
10:30:06.172 -> entry 0x4004c18c
@Kartman